# Difference between datetimes in a list

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list, called `times`, with datetime values in python. I want to take the difference between every other value in the list and the one preceding it. For example, I have

```
[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(7, 51, 10), datetime.time(7, 51, 20), datetime.time(12, 51, 50), datetime.time(12, 52), datetime.time(16, 34, 30)]
```

I would like the same list or a new list to be filled with the values:

```
[datetime.time(7,51,10) - datetime.time(0, 0, 0), datetime.time(12, 51, 50) - datetime.time(7, 51, 20), datetime.time(16, 34, 30) - datetime.time(12, 52, 0)]
```

I think I need to iterate through my original list with a `for` loop and perform calculations with `timedelta`.

Here is my setup of the `for` loop:

```
for i in times:
     (something with timedelta between i+1 from i)
     i+2
```

Does anyone have any advice as to where to begin?

**EDIT:**

I figured out how to convert from datetime.time to datetime.datetime. It looks like this:

```
dt = []
for i in times:
    dt.append(datetime.combine(date.today(), i))

print(dt)
```

This array now as datetimes. I think I can figure out how to do `timedelta` between these values now, but I'd still like any advice anyone might have.

Comment: I would recommend starting with writing a `for` loop as you already suggested...

Comment: After that, you'll want to look into `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'` because you cannot find a `timedelta` between `datetime.time` objects, only `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: @BenT added some starter code for a for loop.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the advice. I see that on my end and I'll look for how to convert from datetime.time to datetime.datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using comprehensions to solve this problem.

```
import datetime

times = [datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(7, 51, 10), datetime.time(7, 51, 20), datetime.time(12, 51, 50), datetime.time(12, 52), datetime.time(16, 34, 30)]

base_date = datetime.date.min

datetimes = [datetime.datetime.combine(base_date, time) for time in times]
starts = datetimes[::2]
ends = datetimes[1::2]

timedeltas = [end - start for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]
```

Here we avoid using for loops by using list comprehensions and zipping together two partial views of our list of datetimes.

This solution assumes all times occur on the same day and that the list is non-empty.

Comment: You could also write `timedeltas = [datetimes[i] - datetimes[i-1] for i in range(1, len(datetimes))]`. I think it's easier to understand, and it avoids a lot of list copying. I like the fact that you're using `datetime.date.min` instead of `datetime.today()`!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the simplest way would be:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.diff(dt)[::2]
```

where `dt` is the converted list of datetime.datetime(s). The result in `res` is

```
array([datetime.timedelta(0, 28270), datetime.timedelta(0, 18030),
       datetime.timedelta(0, 13350)], dtype=object)
```